# LDAP query operational attributes

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

I'm using the `System.DirectoryServices` library to query against a LDAP directory. I'm seeing all the text attributes fine, but I need to retrieve some operational attributes like `pwdChangedTime`. I get an object not set to an instance of the object' type error when trying to get these properties.

```
using (DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(dirCon,
                    ldapSearchFilter.Replace("{cn}", cn),
                    new string[] {"*","+"},
                    SearchScope.Subtree))
{
   foreach (SearchResult sr in search.FindAll())
   {
       la = new LdapAccount();
       la.pswdUpdateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(sr.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["pwdchangedtime"].ToString(), dateFormat, null);
...
}
```

I see all the text attributes but it won't find any operational attributes.

Comment: @marc_s LDAP is actually rather *unpicky* about case, especially in attribute names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing some testing locally I see the property `pwdlastset` on the `SearchResult`, so I wonder if the property names are not what you expect them to be.

```
result.Properties["pwdlastset"]
```

There is also a `PropertyNames` collection on the SearchResult Properties collection that might be useful.  Also, when I have queried AD before I did not call `GetDirectoryEntry()` but just enumerated the properties directly from the SearchResult.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the confusing thing is that when I look at the PropertyNames collection (and the underlying hashtable) i see an entry for 'pwdchangedtime' and it has the correct dateTime value in it.  I have no idea why i can't extract this from the collection....

Comment: That is interesting.  So `sr.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["pwdchangedtime"].ToString()` is the piece that is throwing the exception?  Or is it some other line.  I would think that if you could get a reference to the DirectoryEntry and view the underlying property in visual studio that you should be able to do the same thing in code...

Comment: correct I get a null pointer there.  Its wierd.  I would understand the null pointer if the attribute wasn't coming back, but it is...

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what is going on then.  When I run that bit of code with .ToString() I get "System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection"

Comment: Talked to some colleagues and they pointed me to this syntax which works:
DateTime test=(DateTime)sr.Properties["pwdchangedtime"][0];